# AssertJ List of String Must Exist In Expected, Ignoring Duplicates

Tags: assertj

I have a expected List of Strings:

```
List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
```

I want these assertions be evaluated with these results:

```
{"a", "a", "b", "b"} -> true
{"a", "b", "c"} -> false
```

Essentially, I want assertJ to ignore/remove any duplicates that is being evaluated. How can I do this with the Assertions API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`containsOnly`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.12.2/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#containsOnly-ELEMENT...-), to quote the javadoc:

> Verifies that the actual group contains only the given values and nothing else, in any order and ignoring duplicates (i.e. once a value is found, its duplicates are also considered found).

Comment: According to the doc, the iterable version of this method is what I need: `containsOnlyElementsOf`.